# Problems with Reddit SDK (API)

Tags: php, reddit

I'm trying to get the last posts of a subreddit - I'm using the jcleblanc reddit sdk (https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk) and I don't know why It's not working - I receive the following message ewhen I try to acess my website 
403 Forbidden 
Request forbidden by administrative rules.

The https://ssl.reddit.com/prefs/apps is configured okay - I just don't know why It's not working. I'm using the following function:

```
<?php
$reddit = new reddit();
$response = $reddit->getListing("calculus", 5);
print $response
?>
```

It'd be nice to have some help - I'm not any expert developer, just trying to make something.
Thanks :-)

Hey guys - I managed to get it working using an old version of that don't uses OAuth.

```
$reddit = new reddit($USER, $PASS);
print_r($reddit);
print_r($reddit->getListing("calculus", 1));
```

It's working! but, on the page I receive all the information, for example:

```
reddit Object ( [kind] => Listing [data] => stdClass Object ( [modhash] => jvfddbr7sg6a1787beebf94c0a61cc4c2be6e5fb2106da9f4b [children] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [kind] => t3 [data] => stdClass Object ( [domain] => self.leagueoflegends [banned_by] => [media_embed] => stdClass Object ( ) [subreddit] => leagueoflegends [selftext_html] => [selftext] => [likes] => [user_reports] => Array ( ) [secure_media] => [link_flair_text] => [id] => 2papx0 [gilded] => 0 [secure_media_embed] => stdClass Object ( ) [clicked] => [report_reasons] => [author] => Azberg [media] => [score] => 2217 [approved_by] => [over_18] => [hidden] => [thumbnail] => self [subreddit_id] =>
```

I'd like to know how can I select only some of the items abovve - like domain, or likes, or anything. I tried but I can't manage it to work. Sorry for the newbiness - I really tried to fix this.
Thanks in advvance!

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the latest API. Anyways, did you fill out the information in `config.php`?

According to the documentation, you have to "post the key and secret into the appropriate sections" in your `config.php` which is this file:

https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk/blob/master/config.php

Specifically these two variables

```
...
static $CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR CLIENT ID';
static $CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET';
...
```

Comment: Yes I did but It didn't work, so I switched to the old version. It works fine, but I'm getting all the information (who posted, name of the post, date, etc) and I'd like to to get only some of this info. Thank you for replying!